# How to separate column in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have DataFrame containing values about shops and categories in one column.

| Date | Spent | ... | Category/Shop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-04 | 126.98 | ... | Supermarkets |
| 2022-08-04 | NaN | ... | ShopName |
| 2022-08-04 | 119.70 | ... | Supermarkets |
| 2022-08-04 | NaN | ... | ShopName |

...

I need to separate last column into to columns:

| Date | Spent | ... | Category | Shop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-04 | 126.98 | ... | Supermarkets | ShopName |
| 2022-08-04 | 119.70 | ... | Supermarkets | ShopName |

How can this be done?

We can assume that every second row in the Category/Shop column contains the name of the store that needs to be moved to a new column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the sample and expecting future similar behavior I would do it with groupby

```
df = df.fillna(method='ffill').groupby(['Date','Spent'])['Category/Shop'].apply(list).reset_index()
df['Category'],df['Shop'] = df['Category/Shop'].str[0],df['Category/Shop'].str[1]
df = df.drop(columns='Category/Shop')
```

Outputting:

```
         Date   Spent      Category      Shop
0  2022-08-04  119.70  Supermarkets  ShopName
1  2022-08-04  126.98  Supermarkets  ShopName
```

Comment: Apparently I unsuccessfully showed that the DataFrame is wider than this, but the DataFrame has 21 columns. The principle of operation should be about the same?

Comment: Yes, try passing all the columns to the `groupby()` and keep the `['Category/Shop']` as the aggregated column.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the pandas series str. split() function on the “Address” column and pass the delimiter (comma in this case) on which you want to split the column. Also, make sure to pass True to the expand parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for `iloc` to retrieve every second row, and build a new dataframe with `pd.concat`.

Given `df` is your source DataFrame, it would look like this:

```py
pd.concat(
    [
        # start at the first row and use every 2nd row of df
        df.iloc[::2].reset_index(drop=True),
        # start at the second row and use every 2nd row of df, but only the last column
        df.iloc[1::2]["category/shop"].reset_index(drop=True)
    ],
    # concatenate along columns
    axis=1
)
```

Output:

```
         date   spent category/shop category/shop
0  2022-08-04  126.98  Supermarkets      ShopName
1  2022-08-04  119.70  Supermarkets      ShopName
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use a list comprehension as follows

```
df['Category'], df['Shop'] = zip(*[('Supermarkets', 'ShopName') if x == 'Supermarkets' else ('ShopName', 'ShopName') for x in df['Category/Shop']])

[Out]:

         Date   Spent Category/Shop      Category      Shop
0  2022-08-04  126.98  Supermarkets  Supermarkets  ShopName
1  2022-08-04     NaN      ShopName      ShopName  ShopName
2  2022-08-04  119.70  Supermarkets  Supermarkets  ShopName
3  2022-08-04     NaN      ShopName      ShopName  ShopName
```

Then, as one doesn't need the rows where `Spent` is `NaN`, nor the column `Category/Shop`, one can drop both with [`pandas.DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['Spent']).drop(columns=['Category/Shop'])

[Out]:

         Date   Spent      Category      Shop
0  2022-08-04  126.98  Supermarkets  ShopName
2  2022-08-04  119.70  Supermarkets  ShopName
```

or, if one wants to reset the index, pass, as well, [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['Spent']).drop(columns=['Category/Shop']).reset_index(drop=True)

[Out]:

         Date   Spent      Category      Shop
0  2022-08-04  126.98  Supermarkets  ShopName
1  2022-08-04  119.70  Supermarkets  ShopName
```